# Facing issue with sbt dependency

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-phoenix

I try to use the phoenix-spark jar to laod phoenix table to Spark 2.2.3 DataFrame

adding this dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-spark2" % "4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5"
```

I tested this two resolvers one by one:

```
resolvers += "Hortonworks Repository" at "http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/"
resolvers += "Hortonworks Releases" at "http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/"
```

I had the folowing error:

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_261)
[info] loading project definition from /home/ambac61n/IdeaProjects/phoenix_test/project
[info] loading settings for project phoenix_test from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to phoenix_test (in build file:/home/my_user/IdeaProjects/phoenix_test/)
[info] sbt server started at local:///home/ambac61n/.sbt/1.0/server/0c2856c06fe3f2cf2706/sock
sbt:phoenix_test>
[info] Defining Global / sbtStructureOptions, Global / sbtStructureOutputFile and 1 others.
[info] The new values will be used by cleanKeepGlobs
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] set current project to phoenix_test (in build file:/home/ambac61n/IdeaProjects/phoenix_test/)
[info] Applying State transformations org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks from /home/my_user/.local/share/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/Scala/repo/org.jetbrains/sbt-structure-extractor/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2018.2.1+4-88400d3f/jars/sbt-structure-extractor.jar
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] set current project to phoenix_test (in build file:/home/my_user/IdeaProjects/phoenix_test/)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last update' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-spark2:4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/ambac61n/.ivy2/local/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-spark2/4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/phoenix/phoenix-spark2/4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5/phoenix-spark2-4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5.pom
[error]   not found: http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/phoenix/phoenix-spark2/4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5/phoenix-spark2-4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5.pom
[error] (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-spark2:4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/ambac61n/.ivy2/local/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-spark2/4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/phoenix/phoenix-spark2/4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5/phoenix-spark2-4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5.pom
[error]   not found: http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/phoenix/phoenix-spark2/4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5/phoenix-spark2-4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5.pom
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 22 août 2020 05:56:14
[info] shutting down sbt server
```

Do you have any Idea?

Comment: `// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-spark2
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-spark2" % "4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5"
`

Comment: @Lamanus yes, this is the dependency that I use

Comment: Once you visit https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/phoenix/, there is no spark2 and you should set the difference repo.

Comment: @Lamanus, but does the line resolvers += "Hortonworks Repository" at "http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/" should do the job?

Comment: go to and find too. you cannot find it. https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/phoenix/phoenix-spark2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After vising those repositories, I noticed that there is no package, indeed.

For the first repository,

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/phoenix/
- No package for the phoenix-spark2

and the second repository,

- https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/phoenix/phoenix-spark2/
- No package for the 4.7.0.2.6.5.1102-5 version

Try with the other versions.

Comment: Thank you, I used this one: "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-spark2" % "4.7.0.2.6.2.0-205"